# Are most ICOs based on Ethereum's Smart Contracts or other technology?

Tags: ether, ico

where can I find an overview of the technologies that blockchain startups use?

Are most ICOs based on Ethereum's Solidity Smart Contracts, creating a simple ERC20-compatible token?

Why are the alternatives like Hyperledger, Chain, Bitstake not so common?

Answer (score 0):

At the writing of this [TokenMarket lists 493 token projects for Ethereum](https://tokenmarket.net/blockchain/ethereum/assets). This is from total 720 projects. Thus, it can be said most token projects are on the top of Ethereum.

Comment: Thanks, these seem to be rather unknown companies.
Are the ICOs with the highest volumes also ethereum-based or they have their own proprietary blockchain solution?

Comment: Bancor, Status.im are Ethereum based and did $100M+. EOS.io raises in ETH and has raised $500M+ thus far (still going). However EOS will map tokens back to their native blockchain via private key swapping. The infamous Tezos also plans to roll their own blockchain if they do not go to jail first.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa https://tokenmarket.net/blockchain/ethereum/assets link is dead